# Why am I getting wrong imaginary number?

Tags: c, complex-numbers, euler-angles

I want to collect polar coordinate values by converting them to Cartesian values in C.

But I'm getting wrong values at `12°`:

```objectivec
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>

int main()
{   
    int desire=1;
    int wind[desire];
    for (int i = 0; i < desire; i++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter degree of wind:");
        scanf("%d",&wind[i]);
    }
    
    double complex sum=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < desire; i++)
    {
        sum=cos(wind[i])+ sin(wind[i]) * I;
    }

    double convert(double radian); 

    printf("\n %.2f %.2fi",creal(sum),cimag(sum));
    double r =hypot(creal(sum),cimag(sum));
    double angle= convert(atanf(creal(sum)/cimag(sum))) ;

    printf("\n %.2f %.2f",r,angle);

    return 0;
}
```

returning completely wrong sine(imaginary value)

```
0.84 -0.54i
1.00 -57.55
```

It should print`0.97 +0.20i` not `0.84 -0.54i`.
What is wrong?

The `convert` function:

```c
#include <math.h>
#include "convert.h"
double convert(double radian)
{
    return(radian * (180/M_PI));
}
```

Comment: `sum=` don't you mean like `sum +=`?

Comment: Right, I fix to one value not need to sum many values. It is just test whether works the some functions or not.

Comment: Trigonometric functions use radian and not degrees.

Comment: If you're using `double` values, you probably should use `atan()` instead of `atanf()` also.

Comment: Tip (or not): you can `#include <tgmath.h>` and have the compiler pick `atan` function type automatically.

Comment: It is unusual to have prototypes in the middle of the code. I usually see them in *header files* or at the top of the source file, right after the `include`s.

Comment: @pmg or rather have `#include "convert.h"` right after `#include <complex.h>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [**7.12.4.6 The sin functions**](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12.4.6p2) (bolding mine):

> The sin functions compute the sine of x (**measured in radians**).

`cos()` is similar.

You're entering 12 *radians*.